# Java android EventBus No subscribers registered for event class

Tags: java, android

In activity I do this:

`onCreate()`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

and I override this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
  EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
  super.onStop();
}
```

And in my service I did this:

```
Global.getInstance().getGeoLocation().setBestLocation(loc);
EventBus.getDefault().post(new EventLocation(loc));
```

And in logsd I see this:

```
10-27 09:15:04.367 5097-5097/komunal W/EventBus: Subscriber to unregister was not registered before: class komunal.activities.PGOListActivity
10-27 09:15:04.458 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class komunal.events.EventLocation
10-27 09:15:04.458 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
10-27 09:15:05.425 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class komunal.events.EventLocation
10-27 09:15:05.425 5097-5097 komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
10-27 09:15:06.458 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class komunal.events.EventLocation
10-27 09:15:06.459 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
10-27 09:15:07.435 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class komunal.events.EventLocation
10-27 09:15:07.436 5097-5097/komunal D/EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent
```

Comment: Is your activity on same process as Service? Eventbus cant work across different processes.

Comment: Share `PGOListActivity` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to only register the subscriber once. So, if you've already registered in `onCreate` don't register it again in `onStart()`.

Second, whenever your activity is no longer visible, you're activity will be unsubscribed from the event. This is because you have the following:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Instead, you need to move the unregistering to the `onDestroy()`:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Last, you need to subscribe to the `Event` in your activity with something like this:

```
// process the event in the Main thread.
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN) 
public void onMessageEvent(EventLocation event) {
  // do something with the event.
}
```

Comment: I did this and it doesn't help me

Comment: Have you really register the activity? you can check with `EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this);`

Comment: Yes it works one time but when my screen is off and next is on I see No subscribers registered for event

Comment: Did you unregister the EventBus in `onPause()`? You need to unregister the subscriber only in `onDestroy`. There's a typo in my answer, I'll update it. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yes I remove onPause and put unregistry to Destoyed

Comment: When I lock a screen I see that No subscribers registered

Comment: Very strange... It looks like the activity is unregistered when your screen is off then on. Try adding the following: `@Override
protected void onStart() {
  super.onStart();
  if (EventBus.getDefault.isRegistered(this)) {
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
| }` then check for it.